# How to dispaly post informations (such as titles) in an admin plugin menu page?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, loop, wpdb

I'm trying to develop a WP plugin to show post(or page) related information (such as show all post title in a list) in an admin menu page. I tried to use "The Loop", but it seems like "The Loop" cannot be accessed in Dashboard.

I have achieved my goal by using $wpdb to query database directly.

But is there a better or safer way to load post information in a dashboard menu page?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The loop can't be accessed in dashboard? Sure you can!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was my mistake, the loop can be accessed in the admin panel